# Firebase Dynamic Links on iOS/React Native only working when app is running

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using [Firebase's Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) (8.11.0) to open a React Native (0.66.4) app with a specific URL.

In my `AppDelegate.m` file, I'm handling the URL this way:

```objectivec
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
            options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  NSLog(@"openURL url %@", url);
  FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:url];
  
  if (dynamicLink) {
    if (dynamicLink.url) {
      NSLog(@"dynamicLink.url %@", dynamicLink.url);
      return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:dynamicLink.url options:options];
    }
  }
  return [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:url
                                                  completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (dynamicLink) {
      if (dynamicLink.url) {
        NSLog(@" dynamicLink.url %@", dynamicLink.url);
        [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:dynamicLink.url options:options];
      } else {
        [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
      }
    } else {
      [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
    }
  }];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:
#if defined(__IPHONE_12_0) && (__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_12_0)
(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#else
  (nonnull void (^)(NSArray *_Nullable))restorationHandler {
#endif  // __IPHONE_12_0
        FIRDynamicLink *dynamicLink = [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] dynamicLinkFromCustomSchemeURL:userActivity.webpageURL];
    
        if (dynamicLink) {
          if (dynamicLink.url) {
            NSLog(@"dynamicLink.url %@", dynamicLink.url);
            return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:dynamicLink.url options:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
          }
        }
    
        return [[FIRDynamicLinks dynamicLinks] handleUniversalLink:userActivity.webpageURL
                                                 completion:^(FIRDynamicLink * _Nullable dynamicLink, NSError * _Nullable error) {
          if (error) {
            NSLog(@" dynamicLink.url ERROR %@", error);
          }
          if (dynamicLink) {
            if (dynamicLink.url) {
              NSLog(@" dynamicLink.url %@", dynamicLink.url);
              // ******** This line is executed as expected in both cases *******
              [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:dynamicLink.url options:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
            } else {
              [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:userActivity.webpageURL options:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
            }
          } else {
            [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:userActivity.webpageURL options:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];
          }
        }];
  }
```

My `Info.plist` file specifies my custom domain:

```xml
<key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
<array>
  <string>https://join.mysite.app</string>
</array>
```

And my Associated Domains specify

```
applinks:join.mysite.app
```

With this in place, my React Native code, via `Linking.getInitalURL()` is receiving the `link` (specified [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters)) that I expect, but **only if the app is already running when the short link is clicked**.

When my app is *not* running, the same code noted in the comments above is executed, with the same inputs and outputs that I expect, but the `Linking.getInitalURL()` call is giving me the short link, not the resolved link that is passed to `RCTLinkingManager`.

I would expect that with the same code path/data, the behavior would be the same, but it's only correct when the app is already running.  Am I missing a step?

**Edit for clarification:**  Ultimately, the behavior I expect is that when a user clicks a link like https://join.mysite.app/slug_here, The code above resolves that into something like https://some.other.link/?some=data, which is fed to the app and used.  This is happening as expected, but only when the app is running, not when closed and launched via a dynamic link URL.

Answer (score 0):

**Original answer:**

From the sample, you shared you only implemented the `continueUserActivity` method that intercepts links when the application is already open.

You also need to implement `openURL` method like their documentation states [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive#:%7E:text=application%3AopenURL%3AsourceApplication%3Aannotation)

In the end, I would highly advise using an already build [library](https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage) that works with react-native

If you really insist on building this functionality on your own, at least you can check out their source code [here](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/tree/main/packages/dynamic-links)

**Edit:**

If you are using the `@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links` then you don't need to write the custom native code yourself, the library will take care of that.

What you need to do is handle the javascript part by adding the [following code](https://rnfirebase.io/dynamic-links/usage#backgroundquit-events)

Here's a sample of how I usually do it inside `react-navigation` using [DeepLinking](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/)

```
import React from "react";
import {
  NavigationContainer as ReactNativeNavigationContainer,
  LinkingOptions,
} from "@react-navigation/native";

import dynamicLinks from "@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links";

import { Linking } from "react-native";

const config: LinkingOptions["config"] = {
  screens: {
    Home: {
      path: "home",
    },
  },
};

const prefixes: LinkingOptions["prefixes"] = ["https://example.com"];

export const NavigationContainer: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const linking: LinkingOptions = {
    config,
    prefixes,
    subscribe(listener) {
      const onReceiveURL = ({ url }: { url: string }) => {
        console.groupCollapsed(`[Navigation] onReceiveURL`);
        console.log(url);
        console.groupEnd();

        return listener(url);
      };

      /**
       * Listen to incoming dynamic links
       */
      const dynamicLinksListener = dynamicLinks().onLink((link) => {
        return onReceiveURL(link);
      });

      Linking.addEventListener("url", (link) => {
        /**
         * Our dynamic links include a prefix of `/link`.
         *
         * This helps us ignore firebase dynamic links and let that be handled
         * by `dynamicLinks().onLink` above
         */
        if (link.url.startsWith("/link")) {
          return;
        }

        onReceiveURL(link);
      });

      // When the component is unmounted, remove the listener
      return () => {
        dynamicLinksListener();

        Linking.removeEventListener("url", onReceiveURL);
      };
    },
    async getInitialURL() {
      // Check if app was opened by a firebase dynamic link
      const dynamicLinkInitialURL = await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink();

      if (dynamicLinkInitialURL?.url) {
        return dynamicLinkInitialURL?.url;
      }

      /**
       * Our dynamic links include a prefix of `/link`.
       *
       * This helps us ignore firebase dynamic links and let that be handled
       * by `dynamicLinks().onLink` above
       */
      const initialURL = await Linking.getInitialURL();

      if (!initialURL) {
        return;
      }

      if (initialURL.startsWith("/link")) {
        return;
      }

      return initialURL;
    },
  };

  return (
    <ReactNativeNavigationContainer linking={linking}>
      {children}
    </ReactNativeNavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

If you're not using the usual Deep Linking alongside Dynamic links (like for intercepting your website URLs) than you can remove the `Linking` API implementation fully

Comment: Actually, I already am using this library.  I've added the `openURL` code and more details above as well.  Also from what I understand, `openURL` is only ever executed when the app is launched via an app-specific scheme such as `com.mysite://`.  This is confirmed in the behavior of my code.

Comment: @StephenCollinsEdited the original answer to explain how the JS part should be implemented